# React Router Async Routes and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am trying to use the React Router Async API to achieve some code splitting.

I have Currently a main route file and a subroute:

```
// routes/index.js
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: AppView,
  indexRoute: {
    onEnter: (nextState, transition) => {
      transition('/login')
    },
  },
  childRoutes: [
    LoginRoute(store),
  ]
})
```

And then my Login Route looks like this:

```
//routes/Login/index.js
export default (store) => ({
  path: 'login',
  /*  Async getComponent is only invoked when route matches   */
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    /*  Webpack - use 'require.ensure' to create a split point
        and embed an async module loader (jsonp) when bundling   */
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      /*  Webpack - use require callback to define
          dependencies for bundling   */
      const requireUnauthentication = require('containers/UnauthenticatedComponent').default;
      const LoginModalContainer = require('components/Login/LoginModalContainer').default;

      /*  Return getComponent   */
      cb(null, requireUnauthentication(LoginModalContainer))

    /* Webpack named bundle   */
  }, 'login')
  },
  indexRoute: {
    getComponent(nextState, cb){
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        const LoginStart = require('components/Login/LoginStart').default;
        cb(null, LoginStart);
      }, 'login')
    }
  },
  getChildRoutes: (location, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const routes = [
        { path: 'login-start', component: require('components/Login/LoginStart').default },
        { path: 'login-prompt', component: require('containers/LoginContainer').default },
        { path: 'phone-number', component: require('components/Register/PhonenumberSet').default }
      ];
      cb(null, routes);
    }, 'login');
  }
})
```

The problem is when directly navigating to /login I am getting errors:

> DOMLazyTree.js:62     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
>
> ReactDOMComponentTree.js:105   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$nva6m7qemb9ackp2ti2ro1or' of null

I think this is related to the asynchronous route configuration, since as soon as I change something and hot reloading kicks in, everything loads fine.